# See which S3 generic methods are available in environment

Tags: r, generics, methods, amazon-s3

Sorry if missing something obvious here... Is there any way to see in advance which S3 generic methods currently exist in the current environment (say `<environment: R_GlobalEnv>`. A list of all current generic methods in base `R` would do fine but I can't seem to find one.

The reason I'm asking is I'm defining some `methods` for a `class` and some of them will already be generic S3 methods so I'd like to know in advance without having to check each one manually.

For example:

```
isGeneric("mean")
>TRUE

isGeneric("quantile")
>FALSE
```

At the moment the closest I've come is:

```
ls(,all.names=TRUE)[sapply(ls(, all.names=TRUE), FUN=isGeneric)]
```

Which works if I already have a method defined (but doesn't give other potential generic methods) and gives the following error when I give it as a first command in a new `R` session:

```
  invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I doubt that many generic methods will be found within the global environment, they are more likely to be within the environment of a *package*.

Modifying the example from help `?Filter` (which lists all functions in the base package environment) as follows we can filter using `isGeneric`:

```
Filter(isGeneric,ls(all.names=TRUE, env = baseenv()))
## [1] "-"             "!="            "$"             "$<-"           "%%"            "%/%"           "&"             "*"            
## [9] "/"             "["             "[["            "[[<-"          "[<-"           "^"             "|"             "+"            
## [17] "<"             "<="            "=="            ">"             ">="            "abs"           "acos"          "acosh"        
## [25] "all"           "any"           "anyDuplicated" "as.character"  "as.data.frame" "as.difftime"   "as.double"     "as.numeric"   
## [33] "as.real"       "asin"          "asinh"         "atan"          "atanh"         "body<-"        "c"             "ceiling"      
## [41] "close"         "cos"           "cosh"          "cummax"        "cummin"        "cumprod"       "cumsum"        "digamma"      
## [49] "dim"           "dim<-"         "duplicated"    "exp"           "expm1"         "floor"         "format"        "gamma"        
## [57] "intersect"     "kronecker"     "length"        "lgamma"        "log"           "log10"         "log1p"         "log2"         
## [65] "max"           "min"           "names"         "print"         "prod"          "range"         "rep"           "rev"          
##  [73] "round"         "setdiff"       "sign"          "signif"        "sin"           "sinh"          "sort"          "sqrt"         
##  [81] "sum"           "summary"       "tan"           "tanh"          "trigamma"      "trunc"         "union"         "unique"
```

If you need to find what package a function comes from use:

```
find('function')
```

In light of your comment: to search *all* packages on the search path for generic functions, use the following:

```
Filter(length,sapply(search(), function(x) {
  Filter(isGeneric,ls(all.names=TRUE,env = as.environment(x)))
    } ))
```

Note that this is wrapped in another `Filter` statement (to remove elements where  `length==0`).

---

There is also the internal object `.knownS3Generics` in the `base` package environment that will also be useful.

Comment: Great thanks. `Filter` - well met... Was also trying to extend the logic to include other packages loaded by giving their environment but having difficulty feeding this into `ls()`...

Comment: Using sapply on search() , or the subset of the search path which are packages.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another method, using `utils::isS3stdGeneric` in preference to `methods::isGeneric`.

I used the following to get the functions in the `base` package:

```
objs1 <- mget(ls("package:base"), inherits=TRUE)
funs1 <- Filter(is.function, objs)
```

Now remove those with where the body is null (primitives such as `sum`) or is a symbol (`dontCheck(x)`, `force(x)` and `identity(x)` all simply return `x`):

```
genFuns0 <- sapply(
  funs1,
  function(X) {
    if (!is.null(body(X)) & !is.symbol(body(X))) {
      utils::isS3stdGeneric(X)
    }
  },
  simplify=FALSE
)
```

Then

```
head(genFuns <- names(Filter(isTRUE, genFuns0)))
```

gives

```
[1] "all.equal"     "anyDuplicated" "aperm"         "as.array"     
[5] "as.Date"       "as.expression"
```

R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)